# How to export glTF with texture paint

Tags: export, gltf

I am very new to Blender and I am trying to export a model as a glTF file. The model is available on Microsoft 3D Viewer.
What I am doing is as follows:

1. Save the model as .glb from Microsoft 3D Viewer
2. Import the file into Blender (v 2.92)
3. Scale up the model
4. Export it as a glTF file

But when I am doing this, the resulting model has no texture.
What are the exact steps to replicate the original model (with textures) scaled up and export it as a glTF file?

Original Model (The way I want it):
[image: Reaper with texture]

Actual Output:
[image: Reaper without textures]

The Model is a Reaper and constitutes 2 parts; the scythe and body

Material Node Graphs:
[image: Body Graph 1]
[image: Body Graph 2]

Comment: From your description, it should work fine.  Can you add a screenshot of the material node graph after import?

Comment: Hey @emackey, I have uploaded those, could you please check, thanks!

Comment: It's using KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness, which can be imported but not exported. What does Image_5 look like?

Comment: I think it has the structure of the scythe. Here is the link: [link](https://imgur.com/5kciDri)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/272), Blender's glTF importer/exporter works best with metal/rough PBR materials — not spec/gloss PBR materials. Because glTF's metal/rough workflow does include control of the specular parameter (extension: `KHR_materials_specular`), this is just as flexible and generally recommended when using glTF anyway.

Options —

1. Scale the model in a tool that fully supports spec/gloss, like [Gestaltor](https://ux3d.io/gestaltor), or the https://gltf.report/ script tab —

```js
const scene = document.getRoot().listScenes()[0];

// Scales the direct children of the scene, ignoring any descendants.
// Overwrites any previous scale on these nodes.
for (const child of scene.listChildren()) {
    child.setScale([50, 50, 50]);
}
```

2. Convert from metal/rough to spec/gloss before editing in Blender, requires [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/):

```shell
npm install --global @gltf-transform/cli
gltf-transform metalRough input.glb output.glb
```

Comment: I ran solution 2 and confirm it works!